# How to get all values from multiple XML child element for one parent element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have XML file from my supplier. I want to read data from that file. My read.php file contains:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('export.xml');
$result = $xml->xpath("//product");
$array= array();
    foreach ($result as $product) {
        $id = (string)$product->id;
        $code = (string)$product->code;
        $ean = (string)$product->combinations->combination->ean;
        $quantity = (string)$product->combinations->combination->quantity;
        print_r('ID:' .$id. ' CODE:' .$code. ' EAN: '.$ean.' - <b>'.$quantity.'</b> szt.<br />');
}
```

XML looks like

```
<product>
  <id>684</id>
  <code>113</code>
    <combinations>
        <combination>
            <ean>111</ean>
            <quantity>0</quantity>
        </combination>
        <combination>
            <ean>222</ean>
            <quantity>5</quantity>
        </combination>
        <combination>
            <ean>333</ean>
            <quantity>2</quantity>
        </combination>
    </combinations>
</product>
```

It work quite fine but throw's only first combination

```
ID:684 CODE:113 EAN: 111 - 0 szt.
```

but i want also other combinations of this ID

```
ID:684 CODE:113 EAN: 222 - 5 szt.
ID:684 CODE:113 EAN: 333 - 2 szt.
```

Where to find solution?

Comment: `foreach ($product->combination as $combination) {` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add a foreach $product->combinations->combination.

For Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('export.xml');
$result = $xml->xpath("//product");
$array= array();
    foreach ($result as $product) {
        $id = (string)$product->id;
        $code = (string)$product->code;
        foreach( $product->combinations->combination as $combination ){

            $ean = (string)$combination->ean;
            $quantity = (string)$combination->quantity;
            print 'ID:' .$id. ' CODE:' .$code. ' EAN: '.$ean.' - <b>'.$quantity.'</b> szt.<br />';
        }
}
```

Comment: Top notch! Work flawlessly!